# Adding elements to optional arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

What is the proper way to append an element on the end of an optional array? Let's say I have an optional array, myArray, and I want to append '99' on the end. Append() does not work on a nil array, so the only solution I can find is the following, but it doesn't seem very elegant:

```
var myArray = [Int]?()

if myArray?.count > 0 {
    myArray?.append(99)
} else {
    myArray = [99]
}
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use the fact that methods called via optional chaining always return an optional value, which is `nil` if it was *not possible* to
call the method:

```
if (myArray?.append(99)) == nil {
    myArray = [99] 
}
```

If `myArray != nil` then `myArray?.append(99)` appends the new element
and returns `Void`, so that the if-block is not executed.

If `myArray == nil` then `myArray?.append(99)` does nothing and returns
`nil`, so that the if-block is executed and assigns an array value.

Comment: if you want to one-liner-ize it: `(myArray?.append(c)) ?? (myArray = [c])` seems to work. Doesn't even need `_=` in front of it.

Comment: another oneliner:   `snapData == nil ? snapData = data : snapData!.append(data)`

Answer (score 7):

My one liner using nil coalescing:

```
myArray = (myArray ?? []) + [99]
```

Comment: I just saw @rgeorge's comment to @MartinR's answer and it may be more efficient than mine? `(myArray?.append(c)) ?? (myArray = [c])`

Comment: most elegant solution

Answer (score 5):

@MartinR's answer *is* the correct answer, however, just for completeness's sake, if you have an optional and want to do different actions depending on whether it's nor or not you can just check if it's nil (or not nil):

```
if myArray != nil {
    myArray?.append(99)
} else {
    myArray = [99]
}
```

Note that (as you have probably figured out) optional binding doesn't work in your case because the array is a value type: it would create a copy of the array, and append a new element to it, without actually affecting the original array:

```
// Wrong implementation - the new item is appended to a copy of myArray
if var myArray = myArray {
    myArray.append(99)
} else {
    myArray = [99]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using append, try using array merge operator. Because the result is an optional use nil coalescing operator to assign one element array when initial array was nil.

```
var myArray = [Int]?()

myArray? += [99]
myArray = myArray ?? [99]
```

I tried to merge it into one line expression but unfortunately Swift doesn't like it

```
myArray = (myArray? += [99]) ?? [99]
```

Comment: so close:  (myArray?.append(c)) ?? (myArray = [c])