# How to add data to array from Firebase

Tags: ios, database, swift, firebase

I try to use Firebase framework and use it in my app, but I have a problem with undestanding, how to retrieving data from firebase and save it in my own array. Firebase structure is very simple and looks like that:
[image]

Now my code looks like that:

```
`var rootRef = Firebase(url: "https://mathgamepio.firebaseio.com/")


var array:[String]?
var count: Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    rootRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded) { (snap: FDataSnapshot!) -> Void in


        self.count++
        let math = snap.value["math"] as! String
        print(self.count)
        print(math)


        self.array?.append(math)
        print(self.array)
        print("--------")

    }`
```

The result of this operation looks like that:

[image]

`self.array.append` doesn't work and is `nil` always. How to add this data to my own array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your array is never initialized, so `self.array?` will always skip `append`.

One solution is to check of the array exists:

```
if (self.array?.append(math)) == nil {
    self.array = [math]
}
```

There are probably more ways to solve this, but I modified the answer from this question: [Adding elements to optional arrays in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531409/adding-elements-to-optional-arrays-in-swift)

### Update

Even easier is to simply create the array, before using it:

```
var array:[String]?
var count: Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.array = [];

    rootRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded) { (snap: FDataSnapshot!) -> Void in


        self.count++
        let math = snap.value["math"] as! String
        print(self.count)
        print(math)

        self.array?.append(math)
        print(self.array)
        print("--------")

    }
}
```

Or simply not mark the array as optional:

```
var array:[String] = []
var count: Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    rootRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded) { (snap: FDataSnapshot!) -> Void in

        self.count++
        let math = snap.value["math"] as! String
        print(self.count)
        print(math)

        self.array.append(math)
        print(self.array)
        print("--------")

    }
}
```

TIL I learned some basic Swift syntax. :-)