# Optional array is empty after appending elements inside it in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type

My context is as follows: I have a view controller that draws different room shapes. Each wall is a subclass of UIView. The model for the walls is as follows:

```
struct Wall {
  let name: String
  let number: Int
  var length: CGFloat?
  var attachedObjects: [WallObject]?
  var isSelected: Bool
}
```

So each wall has a property that gets assigned one of the above ones. 
When a tap happens on one wall the sender gets stored into an optional variable:

```
@objc fileprivate func changeWallProperties(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    guard let tappedWall = sender.view as? RoomShapeDrawingV else {print("could not get wall"); return}
    tappedWall.wallModel?.isSelected = true 
    selectedWallModel = tappedWall.wallModel
```

I have a collection view that displays objects that can go on the wall. When a cell is selected I get a WallObject type that is another struct for the contents of the collection view, the selection needs to be placed into the model for the selected wall:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let aWallHasBeenSelected = isWallSelected else {print("could not get the selected wall"); return}
    if aWallHasBeenSelected {
        print("a wall has been selected")
        let wallObject = wallObjects[indexPath.item]

        selectedWallModel?.attachedObjects?.append(wallObject)
```

The last line does nothing, [attachedObjects] is nil inside the model for that selected wall. I have found a solution on this post: [Adding elements to optional arrays in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28531409/adding-elements-to-optional-arrays-in-swift)
But I want to know why this happens, if there is a logical error on my behalf or what. Is it because I use structs and I make copies of them, or there is something else happening?

Comment: Lookup "optional chaining" – if  `attachedObjects` is `nil` then `attachedObjects?.append(...)` simply does nothing.

Comment: yes. thank you. that makes perfect sense. reading the chapter now.

Comment: Just change your declaration to `var attachedObjects: [WallObject] = []`

Comment: Note that this is mentioned in the answer that you linked to.