# Is there a one-line version of "create array if nil, otherwise append"?

Tags: swift

Say I have an optional array of Int

`var nums: [Int]?`

I'd like to append result to nums if not nil, else assign result to nums directly.

Something like this:

```
if nums == nil {
   nums = result 
} else {
   nums?.append(contentsOf: result)
}
```

Is there a simpler or more graceful way to do this?

Comment: Why would you need an optional array? Just initialize it with an empty collection

Comment: @LeoDabus Aren't there situations where "empty" and "non-existent" are distinct states? An example I could think of is JSON parsing....

Comment: @Sweeper if you use your approach what difference would it make?

Comment: Related: [Adding elements to optional arrays in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28531409/1187415)

Comment: @LeoDabus the nil might not matter in the situation shown here. Who knows where it will matter? My point is that it is not uncommon to have situations like this, so we shouldn’t discuss irrelevant things like whether they _should_ use an optional or not. In other words, this is not one of those “someone not knowing what they’re doing trying to solve a problem in an obscure way, and we tell them to change their entire approach” situation.

Comment: @Sweeper I've never needed to declare an array as optional. My point is to make the OP think about its usage and if he really needs it. Most of the time (99.9%) he woudn't.

Comment: timeout guys, both of you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```swift
nums = nums.map { $0 + result } ?? result
```

Or, if you find yourself needing it a lot:

```swift
public extension Optional {
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - makeResult: arguments: (`resultWhenNil`, `self!`)
  func reduce<Result>(
    _ resultWhenNil: Result,
    _ makeResult: (_ resultWhenNil: Result, _ self: Wrapped) throws -> Result
  ) rethrows -> Result {
    try self.map { try makeResult(resultWhenNil, $0) }
    ?? resultWhenNil
  }
}
```

```swift
nums = nums.reduce(result) { $1 + $0 }
```

Comment: I would make it a mutating method. The only draw back with this approach is that it would look like the nums is a non optional type

Comment: You could also implement your own append(contentsOf) method constraining Wrapped to RangeReplaceableCollection

Comment: `extension Optional where Wrapped: RangeReplaceableCollection {
    mutating func append<S>(contentsOf newElements: S, default value: Wrapped) where Wrapped.Element == S.Element, S : Sequence {
        if self == nil {
            self = value + newElements
        } else {
             self! += newElements
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way I can think of:

```
nums = (nums ?? []) + result
```

`+` can be used to concatenate arrays too!

Comment: this is the best quick solution, thank you @Sweeper but sorry I marked Jessy solution because the extension helps for my case :)