# How to create an empty, optional array?

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type

Swift 5/Xcode 12.4.

I know how to initialize an empty array:

```
var myarray = [String]()
```

I know how to initialize an optional String:

```
var mystring:String? = ""
```

How do I create an empty, optional Array and initialize it? I don't want the contents to be optional but the array itself, so I can set it to/check it for `nil`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28531881/2016165) suggests using `var myArray = [String]?()` but this just shows a "No exact matches in call to initializer " error in playground.

`var myarray:[String]? = ()` also displays an error ("Cannot convert value of type '()' to specified type '[String]?'").

Comment: Do you mean `var myarray:[String]? = []`?

Comment: `Optional<Array>` is an anti-pattern in Swift. You can represent the lack of value with an empty array, there's no need to wrap it in an `Optional`.

Comment: @Sweeper Oh, it uses square brackets, not round ones. That's it, thanks!

Comment: @DávidPásztor Anti-pattern, sorry? I'm going to fill the array but also set it to "nil" in certain cases. Coming from Java I'm used to checking for "null" instead of `isEmpty` or even "length" (which is obviously a lot slower). Is there a reason why I shouldn't do it the same way in Swift?

Comment: @Neph in Java you can use a null-check because everything (except for primitives) is a reference type, so it can be null. However, in Swift, only optionals can be `nil` and you should only use an optional to a type that can either have a value or not, `nil` represents the lack of value. However, in case of collections, you can represent the lack of value using an empty collection, hence it's discouraged to use optional collections, since they just complicate your interface without any benefits (in most cases).

Comment: @DávidPásztor I know that you then have to unwrap it but that's actually a nice way of showing that the array could be "nil". The question is now what's faster: `= nil` or `removeAll`? If there's no "real" downside to using `nil`, apart from having to unwrap it, I'd rather continue using that because that's what I'm already used to.

Comment: "continue using that because that's what I'm already used to" is also an anti-pattern, though. And not just in programming!

Comment: @Neph you don't need `removeAll`, you can simply set the array to an empty array, like `myArray = []` instead of `myArray = nil`, which should be equally fast. Also whether you are used to this shouldn't really matter, since if you're working on a project with other devs, it's not just you who have to understand the codebase. And if you're working for a company rather than your own project, probably someone else will have to look at the code in the future, so it's even more important for the code to be understandable for everyone.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Isn't creating a new array (even when it's empty) more "expensive" than setting it to null or is that just a thing in Java again? Setting stuff to null/nil isn't "exotic" enough for other people not to understand it, especially with programmers usually having used other languages (that do use that stuff regularely) before. Are there any big downsides to using an optional array, at least performance-wise?

Comment: @Jessy If you're regularely switching between projects in different languages, trying to make stuff as similar as possible is actually a good thing because it takes you less time to get used to/understand again what you've been working on. And yes, I did create `String` overrides in my Swift project, so `substring` and `lastIndexOf` work the way they do in Java. ;)

Comment: @Neph no, it's not more expensive at all. This particular example isn't about readability, it's about best practices and simplifying the interface/call-site. There should be no performance difference between the two. You shouldn't try to write Swift code based on your Java experience, since the two languages are significantly different. When writing Swift code, the particular implementation and design details of Swift itself should be kept in mind, not what other languages are doing.

Comment: hi @Neph I would encourage you, in each language, to follow the correct way of doing things in that language.

Comment: @Fattie This is programming, often there isn't a "correct" way (which answers here on stackoverflow have proven more than once), just less common or more "expensive" ways. ;)

Comment: @Sweeper You commented the correct/working code. Want to post it as an answer?

Comment: hi @Neph - I'm sorry but you're wrong.  There is indeed a "correct" way and that is the way that is *most reusable*.   That's the overarching principle of modern software engineering.

Comment: @Fattie So everyone who's posting alternative working code here on stackoverflow is wrong? There's no set of rules that say what's "forbidden" because that stuff is simply not possible and the compiler's going to complain. In the end it's about personal preferences within the limits of the programming language. It doesn't matter if you add a line break before each "{" or if you're using `a = a+b` or `a+=b`, they give you the same result and neither way is wrong, yet everyone knows what it means.

Comment: @Fattie Everyone knows what `=nil` means, so unless you can provide a source saying that it's "bad" (readability- or performance-wise), I don't see a valid reason why you shouldn't use it.

Comment: "on your own" you can indeed program any way "that compiles and runs the way you want".  but as soon as you have a team and reusability - you're in the world of modern software engineering which is entirely about standard standards.  say you came up with some fantastic thing (a great control in iOS, some amazing AI routine, a great image processing library, or whatever), and you put it on github, and it became loved and popular.  anything "weird" you wrote (don't even mention weird formatting) would simply be ........... instantly changed, that is to say fixed, by everyone else.

Comment: i hope these thoughts clarify what I mean.  Good luck !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you *really* want to do it:

```
var myArray: [String]? = []
```

Array literals are denoted by `[]`. not `()`. `()` is an empty tuple.

However, as people have mentioned in the comments, this is an anti-pattern. If an "empty array" and "nil" don't mean something different to your code, then just use a regular `[String]`, and use an empty array to indicate "nothing".

Also from the comments, you seem to be trying to write Swift code the way you write your Java code. I suggest you don't do that. When in Rome, do as the Romans do :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. An empty array and a nil array are two different things in my code: If it's empty it just hasn't been filled yet (but there is data), if it's nil then it can never be filled because the data for it simply doesn't exist. I need a way to differentiate that and an optional array is the best way to do this without adding and setting an extra `bool` in x different spots.